# php move_uploaded_file() doesn't work in production

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, webserver

So this is my problem:
Im hosted on tsrato and want to upload a file to my Webserver, I was too lazy to create my own, because this problem is haunting me for days now. The Webserver has got a tmp Directory I think and I don't have the accessebility to redirect ther tmp directory to my uploads folder.
So how can I send the file dirextly to htdocs and in my uploads folder.
the php Code below is in a other directory called inc.
The size of the file doesnt matter and the security I just want to get one file moved to my directory.
This is the directory to my Webspace
/mnt/rid/XX/X2/51XX52582/htdocs/

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"] > 500000000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error if you try to run this code?

Comment: What error do you get? Is your `uploads/` folder writable? Have you tried using the full path?

Comment: I get an error by moving the file, the last part of the code, it cant tranfer the file properly

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you `/uploads` folder is writable. If its not writable and you don't have the permissions the files will not be transferred.

Comment: I have permisson to my own folder, its on the webspace, I think the problem is the tmp_directory. Which I dont know where it is at.